How to create an Apex Class or Triggers in professional edition + API, already integrate with JIRA
I Want to achieve this automation - When any opportunity goes to Need Analysis stage, then it will automatically create a JIRA ticket on Jira Projects.
For that i need a trigger in professional edition linked with Jira?
How i can achieve this thing?

Welcome to SFSE! Please take the tour and read How to Ask. You will need to edit your question to include more details like share what you have tried?

Simply put, you can't do this on Professional Edition.
If there's an App in the AppExchange that does what you want, which would almost certainly contains its own triggers/code, you'd be able to install/use it.
Aside from that, your only option would be to go through your account rep at Salesforce and pay more to get to at least the Enterprise edition to be able to write Apex yourself.
